# this.x.toLowerCase is not a function - problem with filters angular ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, function, ionic-framework

I hope you are well.

I start developing an app and I am stuck with this problem and I need a bit of help if possible.

I have 2 filters working in a search function using angular - ionic and I am using a select to search for different types of wine. But if I add multiple="true" to be allowed to select more options I get an error saying. : this.x.toLowerCase is not a function

```
search() {
    
    let filters = {
      wineCat: this.wineCat.toLowerCase().trim(),
      wineType: this.wineType.toLowerCase().trim(),
      wineList: this.wineList.toLowerCase().trim(),
    };
    // console.log(filters);
  

    this.wineService.searchWine(filters);
```

```
public fetchNewWine(wineType?: string, wineList?: string) {
let wineArray = [
     new wineRecipe()
            ];
     let filteredWinesArray = [];
    if (wineType) {
      filteredWinesArray = winesArray.filter((wines) => {
        let recipeWineType = recipe.wineType.toLowerCase().trim();
        return recipeWineType === wineType;
      });
    }
]
```

I get the error for the `wineType` its saying is not a function. The `wineType` is connected to the select that can take multiple values now.

So basically I assume I need to see if `wineType` is an array and return when I filter all the `wineTypes` that has the type include?

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To help here, more information will be needed about `this` and what is the value of x. Will it be possible to add more code that is around this snippet that you have posted?

Comment: Hi, I added a bit more code maybe its clearer.  I would really appreciate if you could help me a bit. Thank you @Praym

Comment: ok, but now the title of your post does not match the content in the code. Now there is no  `this.x.toLowerCase()` in your code snippet. This will not make any sense to anyone new reading this question. Kindly also update the title.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let recipeWineType = recipe.wineType.toLowerCase().trim();
```

What is recipe? you mean wines.wineType?

Comment: Yes, there is no 'recipe' so `recipe.wineType.toLowerCase().trim();` will not work

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
let filters = {
      wineCat: this.wineCat?.toLowerCase().trim(),
      wineType: this.wineType?.toLowerCase().trim(),
      wineList: this.wineList?.toLowerCase().trim(),
    };
```

Comment: Does this work on all the browsers? `?` is the new addition to the javascript world right?